# не работает Кластеризация маркеров Google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api

Привет всем. Подключаю гугл карту, на которой расположено несколько точек, точки выводятся, а вот сделать кластеризацию не могу. Нечего не происходит, в консоли ошибок нет. Вот код:

```js
            var map;
            var markers = [];
            var indexMarkersHospital = [];
            var indexMarkersBanks = [];
            var indexMarkersStation = [];
            
            function addNewMarker(data)
            {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: {lat: parseFloat(data['lat']), lng: parseFloat(data['lng'])},
                    map: map
                });
                
                if(data['img'])
                {
                    marker.setIcon(data['img']);
                }
                
                if(data['information'])
                {
                    var information = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: data['information']
                    });
                    marker.addListener('click', function(){
                        information.open(map, marker);
                    });
                }
                
                
                switch (parseInt(data['type'], 10)) {
                  case 1:
                     indexMarkersHospital.push(markers.length);
                    break;
                  case 2:
                     indexMarkersBanks.push(markers.length);
                    break;
                  case 3:
                     indexMarkersStation.push(markers.length);
                    break;
                }
                
                markers.push(marker);
            }
            
            function getMarkers(typeMarkers = [])
            {
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "ajaxMarkers.php",
                    data: { typeMarkers: typeMarkers }
                })
                .done(function( data ) {
                    var dataMarkers = JSON.parse(data); 
                    dataMarkers.forEach( function (el) {
                        addNewMarker(el);
                    });
                });
            }
            
            function setMapOnAll(map, typeMarkers) {
                switch (parseInt(typeMarkers, 10)) {
                  case 1:
                      
                    indexMarkersHospital.forEach( function (el) {
                        markers[el].setMap(map);
                    });
                    break;
                  case 2:
                    indexMarkersBanks.forEach( function (el) {
                        markers[el].setMap(map);
                    });                    
                    break;
                  case 3:
                    indexMarkersStation.forEach( function (el) {
                        markers[el].setMap(map);
                    });                    
                    break;
                }
            }
      
            function initMap()
            {
                var element = document.getElementById('map');
                var option = {
                    zoom: 15,
                    center: {lat: 49.84392946, lng: 24.02629763}
                }

                map = new google.maps.Map(element, option);
                var typeMarkers = [1, 2, 3]; //typeMarkers: 1 - лікарні, 2 - банки, 3 - вокзали
                getMarkers(typeMarkers);
                
                $("input[name='marker']").on('click', function(event){
                    var el = event.target || event.srcElement;
                    
                    if(!$("form#markers input[value='"+el.value+"']").is(':checked'))
                    {
                        setMapOnAll(null, el.value);//скриваємо маркери
                    } else {
                        setMapOnAll(map, el.value);//відображаємо маркери
                    }
                });
                var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map);
            }
```

Библиотеку подключил:

```
<script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js">
    </script>
```

Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Код переделал, кластеризация работает.

```js
        var map;
        var globalMarkers = [];
        var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        var indexMarkersHospital = [];
        var indexMarkersBanks = [];
        var indexMarkersStation = []; 
       
        function setMapOnAll(map, typeMarkers) {
            switch (parseInt(typeMarkers, 10)) {
              case 1:

                indexMarkersHospital.forEach( function (el) {
                    globalMarkers[el].setMap(map);
                });
                break;
              case 2:
                indexMarkersBanks.forEach( function (el) {
                    globalMarkers[el].setMap(map);
                });                    
                break;
              case 3:
                indexMarkersStation.forEach( function (el) {
                    globalMarkers[el].setMap(map);
                });                    
                break;
            }
        }
            
      function initMap() {
          
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 15,
          center: {lat: 49.84392946, lng: 24.02629763}
        });

        var typeMarkers = [1, 2, 3]; //typeMarkers: 1 - лікарні, 2 - банки, 3 - вокзали
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "ajaxMarkers.php",
            data: { typeMarkers: typeMarkers }
        })
        .done(function( data ) {
            var dataMarkers = JSON.parse(data); 
            
            var markers = dataMarkers.map(function(data, i) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: {lat: parseFloat(data['lat']), lng: parseFloat(data['lng'])},
                  label: labels[i % labels.length]
                });
                
                if(data['img'])
                {
                    marker.setIcon(data['img']);
                }
                
                if(data['information'])
                {
                    var information = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: data['information']
                    });
                    marker.addListener('click', function(){
                        information.open(map, marker);
                    });
                }
                
                  switch (parseInt(data['type'], 10)) {
                    case 1:
                       indexMarkersHospital.push(globalMarkers.length);
                      break;
                    case 2:
                       indexMarkersBanks.push(globalMarkers.length);
                      break;
                    case 3:
                       indexMarkersStation.push(globalMarkers.length);
                      break;
                  }

                  globalMarkers.push(marker);
            
                return marker;
              });
                  
             var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
            {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
            
            $("input[name='marker']").on('click', function(event){
                var el = event.target || event.srcElement;

                if(!$("form#markers input[value='"+el.value+"']").is(':checked'))
                {
                    setMapOnAll(null, el.value);//скриваємо маркери
                } else {
                    setMapOnAll(map, el.value);//відображаємо маркери
                }
            });
        });


      }
```